# how to Split record in week of a month

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doj` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

this is my employee table query

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`employee` (`id`, `name`, `doj`, `salary`) VALUES ('1', 'A', ' 2017-01-01', '100');
INSERT INTO `test`.`employee` (`id`, `name`, `doj`, `salary`) VALUES ('2', 'V', '2017-01-09 ', '1000000');
INSERT INTO `test`.`employee` (`id`, `name`, `doj`, `salary`) VALUES ('3', 'C', '2017-01-22', '1000000');
INSERT INTO `test`.`employee` (`id`, `name`, `doj`, `salary`) VALUES ('4', 'f', '2017-01-30', '212321');
INSERT INTO `test`.`employee` (`id`, `name`, `doj`, `salary`) VALUES ('5', 'A', ' 2017-01-02', '123213213');
```

i have to Split record  in weekly wise report of  a month . when i pass startDate and endDate of a month .

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(doj, '%X-%V') AS date,
    COUNT(doj) AS total
FROM
    employee
WHERE
    DATE(doj) BETWEEN CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2017-01-31' AS DATE)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Using given  query i try to find  january record weekly wise  so am getting Output like this which is correct

```
date      total

'2017-01', '2'
'2017-02', '1'
'2017-04', '1'
'2017-05', '1'
```

But i want  that week record also where count is no zero count.

expected output :

```
date      total

'2017-01', '2'
'2017-02', '1'
'2017-03', '0'
'2017-04', '1'
'2017-05', '1'
```

but i am unable to do this please suggest me how to get record from which i can get zero record week count.

Comment: make a other table as date only and left join with it

Comment: in that table what we have to give ? @knowledge....

Comment: '2017-01' like this date

Comment: But we dont knkow how many week will there in month @knowledge....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In databases (like MySQL) which don't have series-generating functions, I always create tables with series. In this case, create a table like this:

```
create table dates(_date date primary key);
insert into dates values
('2016-01-01'),
('2016-01-02'),
 ...,
('2017-12-31'); // as many dates as you need, but see below
```

Then left join to it with the where clause over the series:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(_date, '%X-%V') AS date,
    COUNT(doj) AS total
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN employee ON doj = _date
WHERE _date BETWEEN '2017-01-01 AND '2017-01-31'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

---

Here's a trick to easily add lots of dates, and caters for leap years etc:

```
create table dates(_date date);
insert into dates values ('2000-01-01'); // pick your start date
insert into dates select adddate(_date, (select count(*) from dates)) from dates;
insert into dates select adddate(_date, (select count(*) from dates)) from dates;
insert into dates select adddate(_date, (select count(*) from dates)) from dates;
// etc until you have enough data
```

Every time you run the insert command, the row count doubles. If you run it 12 times you'll have 10 years of dates.

Comment: u knonw how much data we have to insert for this for all year we need to insert .

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment add as many dates as you need. Millions if you have to.

Comment: i have tried same thing and when i excute this code i am getting  NULL, '0'             null
'2017-01', '2'
'2017-02', '1'
'2017-04', '1'
'2017-05', '1'   which is not expected @Bohemian

Comment: yes its correct now bad the Problem is we have to inser all date correct ? or can we use temp table? @Bohemian

Comment: Yes. There is a trick you can use to insert lots of dates. I'll post it a little later ( a bit busy now)

Comment: yes or we can do like this we ll create table and if we pass start date and end date like 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-31 then from 1  to 31 we ll pass and once we ll get output we ll drop it inside procdure @Bohemian can we do like this

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment see addition to answer

Comment: can we acchived this another way coz our App performance becomes decrease when we insert data Dynamically @Bohemian

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment what do you mean "insert data dynamically"? If you're referring to the insert of dates, that happens once per server lifetime. It's a global resource for everyone to use. If you're using stored procedures, you're already in a world of hurt (I've been there - take my advice and do it in the app layer instead)

Comment: Great answer @ Bohemian.